# How to find post category source file in wordpress

Tags: php, custom-wordpress-pages

I create a post category and sub category then add to menu now i want to echo some specific data for each specific category page but i can not find the source file in theme directory.

I also use firebug inspect element but it show only html help me to find exact php source file thanks.

**Here is my code.**

```
<?php

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

        if ( is_category( 'nokia' ) ) {
          echo "<h1> i am iqbal</h1>"
    ?>
    <h1>  i am iqbal </h1> 

<!-- HTML markup here -->

<?php } else { ?>
<h1>
     i am not iqbal
</h1>
<!-- other HTML markup here -->

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: <?php

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( is_category( 'nokia' ) ) {
      echo "<h1> i am iqbal</h1>"
?>
<h1>  i am iqbal </h1> 
        
<!-- HTML markup here -->

<?php } else { ?>
<h1>
  i am not iqbal
</h1>
<!-- other HTML markup here -->

<?php } ?>

Comment: Put your code here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52886229/edit  not in comment

Comment: i have no issue with code only i cant access path for source file to change something

Comment: Try https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-the-file/

Comment: Bundle of thanks you are great